# How to force excel to open text in webbrowser?

Tags: vba, excel

I have to perform alot of searches in Google, so I made a Excel document that simply inserts the text into the google link:

"John" AND “Soccer” OR “Sport”

"Andre" AND “Soccer” OR “Sport”

For example in have the name "John"in cell A1 and I insert it in the following link.

> https://www.google.nl/search?newwindow=1&q=%22**&A1**%22+AND+%E2%80%9CSoccer%E2%80%9D+OR+%E2%80%9CSport%E2%80%9D+&oq=%22&**A1**%22+AND+%E2%80%9CSoccer%E2%80%9D+OR+%E2%80%9CSport%E2%80%9D+&gs_l=serp.3...7614.32351.0.32567.17.17.0.0.0.0.345.1828.8j6j0j1.15.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.3.379...30i10k1.vLZ-hcrrdgg

And it comes out like this:

> https://www.google.nl/search?newwindow=1&q=%22John%22+AND+%E2%80%9CSoccer%E2%80%9D+OR+%E2%80%9CSport%E2%80%9D+&oq=%22John%22+AND+%E2%80%9CSoccer%E2%80%9D+OR+%E2%80%9CSport%E2%80%9D+&gs_l=serp.3...7614.32351.0.32567.17.17.0.0.0.0.345.1828.8j6j0j1.15.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.3.379...30i10k1.vLZ-hcrrdgg

I made this for all the names by simply dragging it down. And these are all links that actually sends me to the page I want to be on. But what i can't is "CLICK ON THEM" no matter what i try i can't make those cells clickable Hyperlinks.

Next step is also that i want to print/Save them using Amyuni PDF. (this is not my biggest concern at the moment)

Is there any way to force the text to open up in a browser? Using VBA for example.

Thank You in advance, if you know a easier way to perform this I would like to hear that as well.

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`Hyperlink( )` Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f)

```
=HYPERLINK(link_location, [friendly_name])
```

Answer (score -1):

you have this example from Microsoft, if the link you want is in A5 :

```
Sub test()

With Worksheets(1)
 .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("a5"), _
 Address:="http://example.microsoft.com", _
 ScreenTip:="Microsoft Web Site"

End With
End Sub
```

you can modify Address:=... by the content of the cell

Comment: Is iT also possible to automatically change the address according to the cells content, or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Address:=.range("a5").value

Comment: Thank you for you comment I made the VBA code work. 
I made it work for the cells A1:C1
Now I wonder wheter I can open those links in just one webbrowser (with 3tabs)

Is it possible to do this?